# New associated site.

Tags: discussion, formatting, stackexchange, se-sites, proof-verification

Although I've not been active on Mathematics.se, on Physics from time to time, there are  people enthusiastic about their new model, very often with an incoherent or incomplete proof.

I'm assuming that the same happens here.

For the purpose of guidance for such enthusiastic souls, who labour without high-level formal education I'd point-out the new beta site [Proofassistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/):

> The term "proof assistant" is usually used to describe a computer
> software that assists humans with developing [formal proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof). A formal proof is a
> finite sequence of [declarative
> sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition) which are
> either:
>
> - an axiom,
> - an assumption,
> - a sentence that follows from one or more of the previous sentences;
>
> and the sequence of sentences must end with no more assumptions
> remaining.

Comment: I haven't done any serious work with proof assistants, but as far as I can tell, the point of proof assistant software, and therefore of the new beta site, isn't "assisting untrained people with writing proofs", which is what your first paragraph seems to be indicating.

Comment: @ElliotYu Fair to say you're correct, but anything that helps people present their ideas formally in a way recognised by the wider scientific community can improve matters for that set (of which I'm a member I confess). I'm now just awaiting the closure of this as a dupe anyhow.